# Signed android apk - network problem

Tags: android, networking, apk, signed

I have signed my app using netbeans and exported it, uploaded to android market, all fine.
On install of the app, it tells me the various permissions that are needed.

However the app cannot get an internet connection, throws network exception. Of course i have internet permission set in manifest file.

This app works perfectly with debug key.

I am using httpclient for networking.

Anyone have any ideas on what the issue might be?

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by cannot get an internet connection (is there a network available that the device cannot log onto)? What permissions have you declared in the manifest.

Comment: phone has internet connection, manifest has <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>, and app works perfectly when signed with debug key

Comment: are you also trying to determine the state of the network by any chance?

Comment: ok, so i added code to check network status, and it has wifi and 3g. And my app works. If i take out this code to check network status it fails once again to connect to a network, how strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add permission to [access network state](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) also then 'ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'